# Why does the service operation takes longer to return than the actual code inside the operation takes to execute?

Tags: c#, wcf, ienumerable

```
[DataContract]
public class SalesRepReturn : BaseReturn
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<LeadInfo> TodayAppointments { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<LeadInfo> TodayKnock { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<LeadInfo> OutstandingLeads { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<LeadInfo> HotLeads { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<LeadInfo> AssociatedLeads { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SalesRepData",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    SalesRepReturn SalesRepData(int salesRepId, float lat, float lon, int distance);

public SalesRepReturn SalesRepData(int salesRepId,float lat,float lon,int distance)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var salesRepReturn = new SalesRepReturn { ReturnMsg = "Enter valid representative Id", ReturnCode = 401 };
        if (salesRepId == 0) return salesRepReturn;
             salesRepReturn.AssociatedLeads = MapLeads(salesRepId,lat,lon,distance);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            LogTimeTaken(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Time Taken for Map Leads SRD " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        salesRepReturn.ReturnCode = 200;
        salesRepReturn.ReturnMsg = Messages.Success;
        stopwatch1.Stop();
        LogTimeTaken(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Entire Method SRD " + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());            
        return salesRepReturn;
    }

private IEnumerable<LeadInfo> MapLeads(int salesRepId,float lat,float lon,int distance)
    {
        var result=_context.Database.SqlQuery<LeadInfo>("GetMappedLeadsByLatLong @salesRepId,@latitude,@longitude,@distance", new SqlParameter("salesRepId", salesRepId), new SqlParameter("latitude", lat), new SqlParameter("longitude", lon), new SqlParameter("distance", distance));
        return result;
    }
```

The above is my WCF service code. You can see I have added time stamps to get processing time. The processing time not even taking a second but where as the response time varies between 2 Sec to 15 Sec in postman. I have no idea what could be the reasons. I expect the method to take under 1 or 2 sec. The size of response on an average is 40KB.

Comment: Is this on a single call or multiple concurrent calls that you get delay?

Comment: @tomredfern it is a single call.

Comment: And to clarify, you're confused as to why the actual service operation takes longer to return when you call it than the actual code inside the operation takes to execute?

Comment: Exactly @tomredfern I'm confused why actual service operation taking longer. I do have a guess that it could be because of time taken for request and response to travel. But the response time having too much of variations. It is never consistent. 1 Sec Processing time to ~20-30sec response time is way too much.

Comment: See my answer - this is a great question but ultimately you'll probably have to accept that it is what it is.

Comment: Another factor maybe if you're hosting the service in visual studio. This will not perform nearly as well as a window service for example.

Comment: Andrew, please can you un-award me the answer as I don't think it's accurate. I'd like to delete it. I think you should create an answer yourself with your solution in it.

Comment: @tomredfern your comment lead me to the answer, So I awarded it even it is not a complete answer. I believe I already edited my question to give a clear idea of a solution to the readers. Anyhow as you requested I'm un-awarding it.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I know you edited the question to include your solution but this is discouraged on StackOverflow. Solutions provided in this manner are potentially unclear. It would be optimal for you to move the solution into an answer and then award it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Certain Inputs From my colleagues on this.Hope this would help any future readers**

Reason Why it is quicker sometimes?

depending on the quantity of data, you'll have that to contend with. Not sure how Postman stores the received data, but if there's any internal objects/dom associated that'll take some time.
As for the 4/3 seconds response that is probably Query/Parameter caching.

More Explanation On Why delay

1. Network Latency (This will purely depend on the route to reach your request to server. Latency time vary based on regions)
2. Request pipeline processing.
3. Method Processing. (if method uses any DB query, it will take time to establish the connection between application and DB server)
4. Serializing the data to construct the response.
5. Render/display the response from the server.

Above all, internet speed will play a vital role.

**Solution:**
Finally, It was the bandwidth of backend DB server. An increase in bandwidth speed decreased the response time to under 5 seconds most of the responses and 10 seconds for the response with 1.25MB size.

But that is not the solution, My front(IIS) end and back end(DB server) communicated using a public IP. We talked to our server provider to make it happen using a private IP and that solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your SqlQuery is not yet executed when you stop the time. It's executed during serialization of your DataContract.

change `return result;` in your `MapLeads` method to

```
return result.ToList();
```

and the Stopwatch processing time should be closer to the actual response time.

You can find more information about the deferred execution of Enitity Framework SQL queries on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks For the quick response. I have tried that before yes as you said it is closer to my response time. But it has huge time difference considering the direct Stored procedure execution in SQL.     I mean when I execute the SP it takes less than a second but the code takes ~20 Sec.

Comment: I have made the change as suggested and tried method and reponse and processing times as below (Response Time 25, Processing Time 19),(Response Time 4, Processing Time 3),(Response Time 24, Processing Time 23). But why this inconsistency?